# Explain the correlation between 7 critical success factors and 8 factors representing firms characteristics with ANOVA

Tags: anova, pca, error, minitab

For my dissertation I need to check if how 7 factors vary is somehow explained by how 24 other factors vary. (how the critical success factors (which are 7) vary is explained by the characteristics of the firms (the characteristics are explained by 24 factors)).
I reduced the number of 24 factors to 8 via a PCA.

So now I should check if the variance of the 7 factors (these are values I extracted from the literature) is explained by how the 8 factors coming out of the PCA vary.

I therefore have 8 factors each of which has 8 observations, and 7 factors each of which has 8 observations (the sample of firms is 8).
I tried to do an ANOVA with responses: the 7 critical success factors and factors: the 8 factors from the PCA. But by doing a general linear model ANOVA it tells me that there is an error and that all factors except the first one cannot be estimated and have been removed. ANOVA error: "The following terms cannot be estimated and were removed: ..."

I have also tried to make an ANOVA general linear model with response: the first of the 7 critical success factor and factors: the 8 factors; so with the idea of making more anova, one for each of the 7 factors; but it gives the same problem.

What could I be doing wrong?
I'm using MINITAB.

Comment: As you have 7 responses and not one as minitab anova seems to expect, you need to use something like manova (multivariate analysis of variance). If that is really appropriate, we cannot say without knowing more contexr&details, so pleas provide that!

Comment: Please change the question to ask directly about the analysis problem (with more details) and change to a more descriptive title!  An important reason for few views and little interest is the uninteresting title!

Comment: Thank you i will change the title and provide more details.

Comment: Your sample size of 8 is another limiting factor here: With 8 predictor variables, you will always get a perfect fit. Start out with simpler methods, and plots. Show us some!